# Changing attributes of a button in python

Tags: python, button, tkinter

After I have created a button or any other object as such, how can I change its properties later on in the code?
For example:

```
b = Button(root, text="button")
```

How do I change the text in `b` or add a command for `b`.
I actually want to change the colour of `b` when it is clicked.

Comment: You can change properties of a Button widget using [config](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method) modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the attributes of a widget after its initialization, use `config`.

```
b.config(text="new text goes here")
```